# Is it possible to get older kernel versions from the android common repo?

Tags: android, git, linux-kernel, porting, android-kernel

I am trying to port the android kernel to a vendor SoC which is currently running the 2.6.35 kernel. I have looked for a while, and it seems that the only Google released kernels which are not made specifically for an existing device can be found here:

https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/common/+refs

The problem is that the oldest version they have there is 2.6.39. Is this there anywhere I can find older kernel versions which only have android specific material on them, or will I have to use this and settle the extra merging conflicts?

I am currently an intern (so I am new to all this..), and the last person in my position was apparently trying to merge the company kernel with something from ARM called "armdroid" (which has all the kernel versions):

http://linux-arm.org/git?p=armdroid.git;a=commit;h=3baa6a09028e75b210a659bc9b5c7631943edd44

This doesn't make sense though, because it looks like this kernel is designed to work with Realview and Versatile Express platforms, so trying to merge it with the code here would only cause more conflicts. No one here knows anything about android, and I can't get a good explanation as to why he was trying to use it.

For what I am trying to do, do you think that I should use the Google common kernel code, or could it be worth looking for a device specific kernel to merge with? And to repeat my main question, is there a way to get the older android kernel source code?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 2.6.35 kernel was used by Gingerbread.
If there is no 'common' kernel, you have to use an old [Samsung kernel](https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/samsung/) and remove the Samsung-specific stuff.

Please note that 2.6.35 was released in 2010.
If that SoC cannot run a current kernel, you should not use it at all.